# Why I got syntax error, when trying to use concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, visual-studio-2022, c++-concepts

I am using Visual Studio 2022, with the latest compiler. I have a problem, when I am trying to create concept definition. I got many syntax error, for example

syntax error: identifier 'has_type_member'

syntax error: missing ';' before '{'

```
template<typename T>
        concept has_type_member = requires { typename T::type; };
```

I have tried many other basic examples about concepts.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Make sure the compiler is set to c++20. The MSVC default is c++14

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, does your compiler support C++20, and did you make sure to pass it command line arguments to indicate your intent to *use* it?

Comment: Add `/std:c++20` to your build options.

Comment: You get "syntax errors" because your compiler does not understand the C++ you are writing. Most likely it is expecting an older version than you are using. Most likely you can tell it to use a newer version than it does by default - try that.

Comment: "I am using Visual Studio 2022, with the latest compiler" - That doesn't mean that it is configured to use the latest C++ language standard by default. It probably is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2022, ISO C++ 14 Standard in enabled by default. `Concept` feature is available since C++20.

To enable ISO C++20 standard for your project, right click on the project name and select `Properties`, under `Configuration Properties` -> `General` -> `C++ Language Standard` select `ISO C++20 Standard (/stdc++20)`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The problem was, that I set the properties in Release and built in Debug configuration.

Comment: That's a very common mistake everyone does while Visual Studio :)-